# Open Share Dialog to Share a File USing ACTION_SEND

Tags: android

I know how to share A text using    ACTION_SEND.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download Link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mtracker2051");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share This App"));
```

I want to share a text file using the ShareDialog.
How can I do it.

I read about this here   http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html     but cound not get much from this link.

Comment: I think what you call a ShareDialog is really an Intent chooser, and you're already using it in your code.

Comment: Yes, But I want to share a Text File.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: I do not know how to use ACTION_SEND. for sharing text file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String fileName = ...
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("*/*");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"Share File"}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "File Name");   
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share File"));
```

Comment: Sharing file URI won't work accross different profiles. http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-compatibility.html#sharing_files